# How to Enable Linux Kernel Driver for 81ry52 chip for Network over Usb

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kernel, usb, driver

How do you enable the linux kernel driver for [a network adaptor based on a 81ry52 chip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0721M2TKM)?

The development board I'm using states the support is enabled by default. It implies this chip is popular. However it is not working, I can see the USB device is inserted but no network interface is created. And I could not find the adapter/chip model in the kernel source. Nor much information could be found on the net either.

Comment: output of `lsusb`?

Comment: lsusb does not show the id. an embedded linux with closed ko. thanks for the idea though.

Comment: as far as I know if you connect something to USB and the USB bus is able to handle it - /no matter if Linux has drivers for it or not/ - then it *will* appear in `lsusb`. So if your device does not appear in `lsusb` then either there is a(nother) USB *bus* on the system, that is not driven by Linux (maybe because it doesn't have a driver for the respective USB chipset or because it can't initialize it or something), or there is a non-Linux problem (USB device not compatible with the USB bus or electrically dead or somethig needs to be set/initialized by BIOS first or such).

Comment: a random thought: did you do `modprobe usbnet`?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek, it usually enumerated by USB Class ID. Real device IDs are needed when driver applies a quirk.

Comment: @0andriy - what's a "real device ID"?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek, I meant USB Device ID.

Comment: No USB ID can be returned by `lsusb`. Not sure what happens. I kind of think what @TomášPospíšek suggested is right. The chip may be misbehaving or the kernel is not able to handle it. We turned to a AmazonBasic "ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet", that works more like a normal USB network bridge/adapter device. This is the link to the AmazonBasic model: https://www.amazon.ca/AmazonBasics-USB-Ethernet-Network-Adapter/dp/B00M77HLII

Comment: (also @0andriy) after thinking about the USB problem, I must retract a bit. My own USB disk usually doesn't appear on `lsusb` when inserted. Regularily I need to unbind and rebind the driver to the bus, sometimes even suspend the laptop to RAM and resume until the external USB becomes visible in `lsusb`. So there must be more that just electric connectivity and the "HW part" of the USB protocol setting things up for devices to become visible on the bus. Much to my frustration I have no idea abot the USB "model". Pointers 2 not too technical "how does USB work" documents would be appreciated...

Comment: There is no cheap delivery to my country, can't help anyhow. Someone who possess it may try to debug and provide a quirk/fix to enable.

Comment: Thanks to @TomášPospíšek and to @ 0andriy for the many shared insights. I sure will take these into account and pay special attention to them if I ever get a chance back to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, this model of the USB to network adapter does not work for Linux. The comments following the original question have many insights and shared experiences on USB in general. There might be many things to be fixed but not clear for now. I'll keep these in mind and hopefully explore more and find out a solution.

Though if somebody else find out a solution. I'll be very glad to know.